# What are the criteria for $A^n=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a real $n\times n$ matrix A, it's $\det$ has to be equal to either $1$ or $-1$. Are there any matrices with $\det A = 1$ but $A^n≠I$?
Shouldn't every such matrix be an element of some symmetric group (rotation) so there should exist some $n$ for which it's equal to identity matrix?

Comment: "$n\times n$ matrix $A$" and "$A^n$" Are these formulas the same $n$?

Comment: Another example:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/2 & 0\\0 & 2}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has det $1$ and $A^n\not=I$ for all $n>0$.

It can be shown that $A^n=I$ for some $n$ iff $A$ can be diagonalized (over $\mathbb C$) and all its eigenvalues are roots of unity.